# Kendo UI Scheduler: How to create Custom templates

Tags: c#, razor, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-scheduler

we are looking for the possibilities to see and use the Kendo UI..

how and where to create the Custom event templates for a scheduler? 
where should i define and create the customAllDayTemplate as mentioned below?
Any e.g?

created a Div with the Id on the page but the Div is also showing up?

```
            Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Scheduler.Screening>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
            .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 10, 00, 00))
            .EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 23, 00, 00))
            .Height(600)
            .AllDayEventTemplateId("customAllDayTemplate")
            .Views(views =>
            {
            views.DayView();
            views.AgendaView();
            })
            .BindTo(Model)
            )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify your event template in a separate script tag with the id you specified like so:

```
<script id="customAllDayTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div>Title: #: title #</div>
  <div>Atendees:
      # for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) { #
        #: resources[i].text #
      # } #
  </div>
</script>
```

Or by calling .EventTemplate like so:

```
  Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Scheduler.Screening>()
        .Name("scheduler")
        .Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
        .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 10, 00, 00))
        .EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 23, 00, 00))
        .Height(600)
        .EventTemplate(
        "<div class='customAllDayTemplate'>" +
            "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/web/scheduler/") + "#= Image #' />" +
            "<p>" + 
                "#= kendo.toString(start, 'hh:mm') # - #= kendo.toString(end, 'hh:mm') #" + 
            "</p>" + 
            "<h3>#= title #</h3>" +
            "<a href='#= Imdb #'>Movie in IMDB</a>" +
        "</div>")
        .Views(views =>
        {
        views.DayView();
        views.AgendaView();
        })
        .BindTo(Model)
        )
```

See the kendo docs examples [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/scheduler/templates.html) and [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler).

Comment: looked in to the event template (not that great) but i guess missed the script tag. Looks like they have a new syntax there..Thanks anyways

Comment: Yeah Kendo templates get finicky in my opinon, I don't much care for their Mvc bindings. Anyway, best of luck.